A basic misunderstanding regarding a quantum algorithm for finding the maximum (Ahuja & Kapoor)
My question is regarding this paper where the authors claim that their algorithm finds the maximum in an unsorted table $T[0,...,N-1]$ of size $N$ in $O(\sqrt N)$ queries to the oracle. However, it's not entirely clear to me why this is true. Below is a summary of the algorithm:

Choose $y\in \{0,1,...,N-1\}$ randomly.
Repeat the following $O(\sqrt N)$ times: Initialize the state $|\phi\rangle=\sum_i \frac{1}{\sqrt N} |i\rangle |y\rangle$ using $O(\log N)$ Hadamard gates. Now apply Grover's search algorithm for finding a state $x$ satisfying $f_y(x)=1$ where $f_i$ is the function satisfying $f_i(j)=1$ if $T[j]>T[i]$ and $f_i(j)=0$ otherwise. Now measure the first register to obtain $x_0$, which will become our new guess $y$.
Return $y$ as the index for the maximum element.

Now here is what confuses me: We iterate step (2) $O(\sqrt N)$ times. In each iteration we apply Grover's algorithm, but then isn't Grover's algorithm itself already making $O(\sqrt N)$ queries to the oracle? In which case the total number of queries to the oracle should be $O(N)$. What am I missing here?

The bit you are missing is that Grovers algorithm runs in O(\sqrt(N/k)) queries where k is the number of valid solutions. If for example we chose y at random initially, then the number of good states on average would be k = N/2 and then the Grover iteration would run in constant time.  They do some more involved calculations of how the expected number of queries grow but this is the reason it doesn't get worse than O(\sqrt(N)) queries on average.
